# User with 1 reputation can answer a protected question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, protected-questions

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/917268/is-typing-into-cmd-exe-a-windows-easter-egg/) is protected since May 23, 07:45.

Still, there are two users who were able to post answers to it, despite having only 1 reputation:

[image]

Both users ([1](https://superuser.com/users/451977/tronic) and [2](https://superuser.com/users/451186/franklens)) appear to have never had any positive reputation (i.e. anything above 1).

Unless I'm missing something obvious, this seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Maybe both had a post removed? (maybe not, just a guess)

Comment: Some have deleted posts, but they haven't gotten any upvotes (in fact, mostly downvotes). Only [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/918709/liquid-cooling-name-brand-laptop) was upvoted once, but that's not enough for 10 rep.

Comment: Removed posts are invisible, right?

Comment: @Patrick To normal users, yes.

Comment: I mean: you can't see a list of my deleted posts.

Comment: @Patrick slhck is an elected moderator on Super User, so all deleted posts are visible in a list on a user's profile page.

Comment: @grg that explains it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of his answers did have an upvote on it, long enough for him to post his answer, and then it was retracted afterwards. But there is also some abuse of the system going on here, and we'll be looking into that.